# Batch sending output to nul not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, text, windows-7, cmd

When I run this code if there is no Num.txt it says that it cant find the file. how do i stop it from saying this i have tried >nul but it doesn't seem to be making any difference.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%x in (Num.txt) do set "d=%%x">nul
echo %d% & pause
```

Does any one know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF EXIST num.txt for /f "delims=" %%x in (Num.txt) do set "d=%%x"
```

IGWS `echo(%d%` eliminates the `echo is off` message should the file/data not be present.

Comment: Thanks. hard to believe that all I was missing was a "2"

Comment: @foxidrive : strange - seemed to work for me. On re-testing, failed. Fixed.

Comment: logical failure. `if NOT exist` or `if exist num.txt for ...`

Answer (score 2):

I added the second line and removed the `>nul`

```
@echo off
if not exist num.txt goto :EOF
for /f "delims=" %%x in (Num.txt) do set "d=%%x"
echo %d% & pause
```